# Did the Romans import worship in response to plagues?

Tags: religion, roman-empire

*[Pan's Travail](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/080185363X)* by J. Hughes mentions an introduction of various gods as a response to plagues near the fall of the Roman Empire, including Aesculapius ("introduced at Rome to avert a pestilence in 293 BC")  and Dea Febris, the Fever Goddess, who became "an important object of worship."

I am having trouble looking for sources that support the conclusion that various deities were introduced/worshipped more as a response to plagues. If you could direct me to any sources, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All answers should have sources.

Comment: 0

YOu say that Pan's Travail by J. Hughes mentions an introduction of various gods as a response to plagues near the fall of the Roman Empire, including Aesculapius ("introduced at Rome to avert a pestilence in 293 BC") and Dea Febris, the Fever Goddess, who became "an important object of worship."  But  293 BC was many centuries before the fall of the Roman Empire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of places that mention the importation of Aesculapius, the earliest of which is Livy [10.46-47](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0026%3Abook%3D10%3Achapter%3D47):

> [6] The many incidents which helped to make the year a happy one served to console the citizens for one calamity, a pestilence which raged in the City and country districts alike. The mischief it did was looked upon as a portent. The Sacred Books were consulted to see what end or what remedy would be vouchsafed by the gods. [7] It was ascertained that Aesculapius must be sent for from Epidaurus. Nothing, however, was done that year, owing to the consuls being engrossed with the war, beyond the appointment of a day of public intercession to Aesculapius.

Valerius Maximus [1.8.2](https://www.attalus.org/translate/valerius1b.html) goes into more detail:

> But then we may relate how favourable the rest of the gods were to our city. For when our city was visited with a three-year pestilence, and neither through divine compassion or human aid could any remedy be found for so long and lasting a calamity, the priests consulted the Sibylline Books and observed, that there was no other way to restore the city to its former health but by fetching the image of Aesculapius from Epidaurus. The city therefore sent ambassadors thither, hoping that by its authority, the greatest then in the world, they might prevail to obtain the only remedy against the fatal misery. Neither did hope deceive them. For their desire was granted with as much willingness, as it was requested with earnestness. For immediately the Epidaurians conducted the ambassadors to the temple of Aesculapius (distant from the city some five miles) and told them to take out of it whatever they thought appropriate for the preservation of Rome. Their liberal goodwill was imitated by  the god himself in his celestial compliance, approving the kindness of mortals. For that snake, seldom or never seen except to their great benefit, which the Epidaurians worshipped equally to Aesculapius, began to glide with a mild aspect and gentle motion through the chief parts of the city; and being seen for three days to the religious admiration of all men, without doubt taking in good part the change to a more noble seat, it hastened to the Roman trireme, and while the mariners stood frightened by so unusual a sight, crept aboard the ship. It peaceably folded itself into several coils, and quietly remained in the cabin of Q. Ogulnius, one of the ambassadors. The envoys returned due thanks, and being instructed by those who were skilful in the due worship of the serpent, like men who had obtained their hearts' desire, joyfully departed. When after a prosperous voyage they put in at Antium, the snake, which had remained in the ship, glided to the porch of the temple of Aesculapius, adorned with myrtle and other boughs, and twisted itself around a palm-tree of a very great height, where it stayed for three days in the temple of Antium. The ambassadors with great care put out those things wherewith he used to be fed, for fear he should be unwilling to return to the ship: and then he patiently allowed himself to be transported to our city. When the ambassadors landed upon the shore of the Tiber, the snake swam to the island where the temple was dedicated, and by his coming dispelled the calamity, for which he had been sought as a remedy.

Dea Febris, on the other hand, is probably more native to Rome.

Also note that this event was several hundred years before the fall of the Roman *empire*, and even a  couple hundred years before the fall of the Roman republic, so I cannot see what it has to do with these events.